# Python library for XSS filtering?

Tags: python, xss

Is there a good, actively maintained python library available for filtering malicious input such as XSS?

Comment: Well anything that removes html tags will do that. Did you have special requirements for things you want kept?

Comment: I'd just like to point out that the comment above is very naive, if you read that, consider also reading: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet as a start.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using a web framework and a template engine like Jinja2 there is a chance that the template engine or the framework has something built in just for that.

There is something in the cgi module that can help you:

`cgi.escape('malicious code here')`, see: http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html#cgi.escape

Also Jinja2 provides escaping:

```
from jinja2 import utils
str(utils.escape('malicious code here'))
```

Comment: Starting with Python 3.4+, there's `html.escape` in stdlib!

Answer (score 3):

You can easily code XSS-defense in Python, see for example http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496942/ for an instructive and usable piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

The [Strip-o-Gram](http://zope.org/Members/chrisw/StripOGram/readme) library looks quite nice. I haven't checked it out properly, but it looks like it does things well (i.e. can whitelist HTML tags you specify, as well as HTML-escaping anything nasty).

Here's the example usage snippet, quoted from that page:

```
  from stripogram import html2text, html2safehtml
  mylumpofdodgyhtml # a lump of dodgy html ;-)
  # Only allow <b>, <a>, <i>, <br>, and <p> tags
  mylumpofcoolcleancollectedhtml = html2safehtml(mylumpofdodgyhtml,valid_tags=("b", "a", "i", "br", "p"))
  # Don't process <img> tags, just strip them out. Use an indent of 4 spaces 
  # and a page that's 80 characters wide.
  mylumpoftext = html2text(mylumpofcoolcleancollectedhtml,ignore_tags=("img",),indent_width=4,page_width=80)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You can't just trust that attackers put in nice tags. Unless strip-o-gram works on heavily encoded tags (see rsnake's list: http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html) this won't work.

Comment: Ditto what Mystic said. Seems like Strip-o-gram (boy does that sound like something you might order to cheer up a lonely friend) isn’t described as a defense against XSS.