# Showing a document to write text on with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, text

I am attempting to design a very basic word processor. I want to have a "page" shown in the background (like you might see on Google Docs, or MS Word) that your text is written on.

How do I draw this page? Should it be an SVG? A stylized DIV? A big canvas? I am very new to designing using the DOM, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: " I want to have a "page" shown in the background" no clue what that means....

Comment: If you try out [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com) then you will see that text is entered into a white rectangle that is on top of some gray background. There is also some shading around the rectangle. This gives the impression of typing onto a sheet of paper. Perhaps this visual aspect is why @HomestuckBrother mentioned the idea of using SVG.

Comment: Yes, a white rectangle that I would enter text on is what I'm after, sorry about the lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be interested in the getting the page-like appearance at [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com/). If so, then check out this really nice tutorial on building a [collaborative text editor with Javascript](https://blog.pusher.com/build-collaborative-text-editor-javascript/). It's well written and introduces concepts gradually and even has a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ankeetmaini/collaborative-text-editor).

I streamlined the example into a single file HTML file that you can play with. This example also uses the `contenteditable` property mentioned in [Armen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47023394/6514691). By the way, the page-like effect is achieved via CSS which I've included within the HTML file using the `<style>` tag.

```html
<html><head><style>
  body { font-size: 14px; line-height: 20px; background: #e8e8e8; }
  .ribbon { height: 200px; background: #3F51B5; }
  .editor { width: 60%; padding: 40px 28px; min-height: 300px;
    background: #fff; margin: 0 auto; position: relative;
    top: -150px; font-size: 24px; }
</style>
<body>
  <div class="ribbon"></div>
  <div id="doc" class="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>
<script>document.getElementById('doc').focus();</script>
</head></body></html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after. I wasn't quite clear, the page I need to display is really just a while rectangle, and this example is exactly that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the `contenteditable` property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp). This actually allows some elements content to be edited by the end user. For example, if I have

```
<div contenteditable="true">Hello!</div>
```

I can actually edit the text and change it as it fits my needs, right from the browser. This will come in handy when you try to implement features like **bold** or *italic* text, and a div element is also much easier to generally style than a huge textarea or input field.
 As a notice, also don't forget about XSS.

Comment: And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086847/div-contenteditable-xss) is a Stack Overflow article on handling XSS ie [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a textarea element and set a specific height and width.

```js
const bold = document.getElementById('bold');
const text = document.getElementById('text');

bold.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (text.style.fontWeight != 'bolder') {
    text.style.fontWeight = 'bolder';
  }
  else {
    text.style.fontWeight = 'normal';
  }
});
```

```css
textarea {
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<button id="bold">bold</button>
<br>
<textarea id="text" placeholder="write text here!"></textarea>
```