# Detect DOM Based XSS website using python

Tags: python, xss, detect

I have a sample url: `http://www.foo.bar/index.php?ids=111`

I've found that it has a vulnerability by `http://www.foo.bar/index.php?ids="><SCrIpT>alert('XSS')</ScRiPt>`

A basic different from normal url and xss url is a alert box has been showed in the browser. But when using python, how can i we see that or detect which url is vulnerability?

I've tried python request library:

```
import requests

xss_url = 'http://www.foo.bar/index.php?ids="><SCrIpT>alert('XSS')</ScRiPt>'
r = requests.get(xss_url);
print r.text

normal_url = 'http://www.foo.bar/index.php?ids=111'
t = requests.get(normal_url);
print t.text
```

Result of r.text and t.text is the same.

Comment: you can check in there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901369/python-library-for-xss-filtering

Comment: @NaingLinAung In my case, it's not XSS defense. It's XSS analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The confirm whether an injection is executable script you could do e.g.

- [Open the URL using Selenium WebDriver and Firefox](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium)
- Instead of `alert()` use `window.exploitDetected = True` as the injection verification
- Wait the the page to load
- [Run JavaScript in the context of the WebDriver](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.execute_script), read if `window.exploitDetected` has been set

Comment: I think using Selenim WebDriver work in this case. But it is too slow because it requires Firefox installed. So when i'm implement on a server without firefox and code can't run on it.

Answer (score 1):

A basic check woule be to to see if your payload is present in the page's source without being escaped, something like this should do the trick :

```
payload = "<SCrIpT>alert('XSS')</ScRiPt>"
xss_url = 'http://www.foo.bar/index.php?ids=">'+payload

r = requests.get(xss_url)

if payload.lower() in r.text.lower(): print("vulnerable")
```

This checks if the payload is present in the page's source, case-insensitive. If the site isn't vulnerable then the payload would be converted to [HTML entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) which while looking the same in a browser are actually different, for example `<` becomes `&lt;`.

Note : this can be used to confirm the presence of an XSS but not to deny the presence of one; for example incorrect escaping would make this return false while the payload may still run in a real browser.

Comment: Besides no escaping, there's also the problem of incorrect escaping, which this approach won't detect.